# API Integration - How to GET data from API and create a list using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, rest, integration

I need a quick help with (REST) API integration. I am trying to GET data from SWAPI (Star Wars API) which is an open API and put those data into the system. This is code that I have written so far.

```
(async () => {
  try {

    const PlanetDetails = await api.makeRequest({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/1',
    });

    var Name = PlanetDetails.data.name;
    var Vehicle = PlanetDetails.data.vehicle;
    var Species = PlanetDetails.data.species;
    var EyeColorr = PlanetDetails.data.eye_color;

    api.setVariable('Name', Name);
    api.setVariable('Vehicle', Vehicle);
    api.setVariable('Species', Species);
    api.setVariable('EyeColor', EyeColorr);

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
})();
```

The problem is that I can get only specific person's data using the ID as you can see in the URL. But I want all the planets name into a list. So I wrote the following code:

```
const PlanetDetails = await api.makeRequest({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://swapi.dev/api/planets',
    });
```

But I am not sure how do I get the Name (attribute) and put it into a list/array.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: _"But I am not sure how do I get the Name (attribute) and put it into a list/array."_ - by looping over the `results` property, and then accessing the `name` property of each item within your loop ... (Btw., this question has rather little to do with APIs themselves in general, it is a question about handling _data structures_. Where you got that structure _from_, doesn't really matter.)

Comment: Side note : `PlanetDetails` is a terrible naming for something that stores a `people` data

Comment: Hi Guys, Thank you for you comments! I have found to way to do that!

Comment: There one more thing that I am unsure of! Depending on the selection of the planet how do I extract the people living on that planet? 

Using Postman when I call 'https://swapi.dev/api/planets/' then then name and other details comes but the residents comes like -> "https://swapi.dev/api/people/1/",  "https://swapi.dev/api/people/2/", "https://swapi.dev/api/people/4/",

How do I extract people's name and that person's other attributes from here?